Is it possible to create multiple users on Linux with the same UID and GID, especially UID and GID 0?
The ArchWiki - rsnapshot page mentions creating multiple users with uid and gid set to 0 as a means of creating users that login remotely to perform backups.

One thing you can do to mitigate the potential damage from a backup server breach is to create alternate users on the client machines with uid and gid set to 0, but with a more restrictive shell such as scponly.

I assume that the purpose is to give those accounts the read-write-execute permissions of the root user with the proviso their login shell gives them reduced rights.
Does that mean that even if accounts have the same gid and uid they are still distinguished by account name and having the same gid and uid gives them same access rights that ?

As far as privileges on the OS are concerned, all privileges are associated with UIDs and GIDs, not names.  Thus, if someone has UID 0 (in the traditional Unix model), they are root, and have all permissions associated with that, regardless of the name that's used to log in.
However, when logging in remotely, you can have multiple usernames for the same ID and provide different shells for each user.  Because the traditional Unix passwd and shadow databases store the shell and other information by username, if you specify an alternate username for UID 0, such as toor (a common alternative on some systems), the shell and password listed in the database for that user will be consulted to determine access privileges and the shell to be used.  Once the login is successful, OpenSSH or the login process will change the user and group to the given IDs and run the specified shell.
Once the login occurs, the process will still have root privileges, but the shell that it's running may permit access to only a limited set of programs.  Assuming the shell is truly restricted and doesn't allow other access, it's possible to limit access in that way.  However, any compromise of that shell (say, due to a bug) will allow execution with root privileges.

There are a few circumstances where usernames are taken into account, mostly during login: the username determines the user entry (e.g. from /etc/passwd) which is taken into account, and any secondary groups (e.g. from /etc/group).
Multiple users can share a given uid, and/or primary gid, but still have different shells and secondary groups. Once a given session’s uid and gids are defined, that’s typically all that matters — processes have uids and gids, not user and group names. Permissions are determined by id, not by name.
It used to be usual enough for systems to have multiple id 0 accounts: one with a regular shell, and another with a statically-linked rescue shell. Backup id 0 accounts, able to copy any file, are not unheard of either (as you mention). Both of these use cases are getting rarer; direct root logins are unusual, recovery systems don’t need static shells, and pull-based backup systems tend to rely on daemons.
